# Why is Instruments marking memory leaks on UIColor and NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, instruments, memory-leaks

I couldn't realize why this code is being marked as having memory leaks:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    MenuViewController *menuView = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuView];
    navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"livreto-verso-horizontal.png"]]; // memory leak here 47,1%
    [menuView release];
    BilheteViewController *rightView = [[BilheteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BilheteView" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
    spliViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, rightView, nil]; // memory leak here 52,9%
    [window addSubview:spliViewController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [rightView release];

    return YES;
}
```

Just the lines marked with problems:

```
navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"livreto-verso-horizontal.png"]]
```

and

```
spliViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, rightView, nil];
```

How do I solve this leaks?

**Update 1**

App Delegate's dealloc method, both navigationController and spliViewController are being released:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [navigationController release];
    [spliViewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leaks tool shows you where something that is leaking, was allocated.

So what it's saying is, after you assigned these values they were never released - which seems like it means your navigation controller is not being released when it should be.

Comment: I've updated the question with the dealloc method that's releasing my navigation controller. I don't think it's wrong. Do you?

Comment: Since you are setting up that view in the app delegate that dealloc should never be called.

Normally though you would never release a navigation controller in a view controller.

Comment: Hi Kendall, so what method should I use to release the controllers on an app delegate? applicationWillFinish?

Comment: dealloc on the application delegate would be the best spot, though really it doesn't matter since your whole application is cleared at that point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the only references to the objects you're seeing leaking are in other objects which are also leaking?

For example, you allocate a navigation controller here:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuView];
```

The UIColor will be retained by that navigationController when you assign it to backgroundColor.

Are you releasing the reference to that navigationController somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the navigationController is released on the dealloc method of my app delegate (same class where its allocated).

Comment: Is there anywhere else you assign to navigationController? I think you may need to post more code. Are there any other objects leaking?